# Why is Visual Studio 2010 telling me "'System.Delegate' does not contain a definition for 'EndInvoke'"?

Tags: c#, begininvoke

Why is Visual Studio 2010 telling me "'System.Delegate' does not contain a definition for 'EndInvoke'" when I call `job.Delegate.EndInvoke()`? How do I fix it? Note that it likes `BeginInvoke()` just fine, and doesn't complain if I add `EndInvoke()` immediately after `BeginInvoke()` (thought hat doesn't accomplish what I want).

I have a little JobTracker class for tracking backup jobs:

```
public class JobTracker 
{
    private class Job
    {
        public Account Account { get; set; }
        public IAsyncResult Result { get; set; }
        public Delegate Delegate { get; set; }
        public bool IsCompleted { get { return result.IsCompleted } }
        public string Instance { get { return Account.Instance } }
    }

    public List<Job> Running = new List<Job>;

    public void AddJob(Account a, IAsyncResult result, Delegate del)
    {
        var j = new Job { Account = a, Result = result, Delegate = del };
        Running.Add(j);
    }

    public void RemoveJob(Job job)
    {
        Running.Remove(job);
    }

public bool IsInstanceRunning(string instance)
{
    return (Running.Count(x => x.Instance == instance) > 0);
}
}
```

These backup jobs will happen asynchronously via BeginInvoke()/EndInvoke(). The calling code (simplified) looks something like this:

```
public void BackupAccounts(IEnumerable<Account> accounts, int maxconcurrent = 4)
{
    // local copy
    List<Accounts> myaccounts = accounts.ToList();
    var jobs  = new JobTracker();

    while (myaccounts.Count > 0) 
    {
        // check our running jobs
        foreach (var job in jobs.Running)
        {
            if (job.IsCompleted)
            {
// PROBLEM LINE:
                job.Delegate.EndInvoke();
                jobs.RemoveJob(job);

            }
        }

        // more jobs!
        while (jobs.Count < maxconcurrent)
        {
            int i = 0;
            Account account = null;

            // choose the next account on a free instance
            while (int < accounts.Count)
            {
                account = accounts[i];
                // instance in use?
                if (jobs.InstanceIsRunning(account.Instance))
                {
                    i += 1;
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    // start the job
                    accounts.RemoveAt(i);
                    BackupDelegate del = new BackupDelegate(BackupAccount, account);
                    IAsyncResult result = del.BeginInvoke();
                    jobs.AddJob(account, result, del);
                }
            }
        }

        // we're all full up, give it some time to work
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

PS - I know this code can be greatly simplified. It's a first, get-it-working iteration -- I just can't figure out why VS doesn't like it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `BeginInvoke`, you're calling it on a *specific* subclass of `Delegate`. When you call `EndInvoke`, you're trying to call it on `System.Delegate` itself, which won't work. Each subclass declares its own `Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`/`EndInvoke` set of methods - which it has to, given that the signatures of the methods varies according to the signature of the exact delegate type you're talking about. If you look at the [documentation for `System.Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx) you won't find any of those methods there.

It's not really clear what your code is trying to achieve, but if you want to call `EndInvoke`, you'll need to make `Job.Delegate` a specific delegate type.

Comment: I didn't include the definition, but you'll notice that I *do* call this on a subclass of Delegate. Under `// start the job` I instantiate BackupDelegate and send it to JobTracker.AddJob(). Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @sh-beta: Yes, you are - look at the compile time type of `Job.Delegate` - it's just `Delegate`. So when you call `job.Delegate.EndInvoke()`, that's trying to find an `EndInvoke` method declared in `Delegate`, not in `BackupDelegate`. That's *why* the `BeginInvoke` call compiles fine - because the compile time type of `del` is `BackupDelegate`.

Answer (score 3):

Because `EndInvoke` doesn't exist on `Delegate`. Instead you should have your Job class hold a reference to a `BackupDelegate`.